# Native Client inner/outer sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, security, assembly, sandbox, google-nativeclient

I am dealing with the Chrome Native Client and have some difficulties in the following points:

1. As I understood so far, the first 64 KB of the 256MB Nacl segment are dedicated to the inner-sandbox. This inner sandbox contains the trampoline and the springboard which communicate from the trusted code to the untrusted and vice versa. When I am in this first 64 KB, can I jump to the middle of 32 byte instructions? for example, if I have a 32 byte instruction in the trampoline, can I jump from this instr to the middle (not 32 bytes aligned) of another 32 byte intruction in the trampoline? Do all the instructions in the trampiline and the springboard are also 32 byte aligned?
2. Can I combine several x86 instructions into one 32 bytes aligned Nacl instruction (for example, putting **AND 0xffffffe0 %eax** and **JMP EAX** in one 32 byte aligned Nacl instruction).
3. I understood that the service runtime is dealing with process creating, memory management etc and that it is accessed through the trampoline, how exactly the trampoline instruction accesses the service runtime? where the service runtime is located in the memory platform? when the service runtime finishes, can it access not 32-byte aligned instruction in the springboard?
4. What the actual duty of the outer sandbox? how does it monitor and filter the system calls? if there is a bug in the validator of the inner sandbox, in what cases it can catch illegal/malicious instruction?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not 100% sure of the top of my head, but I would guess from looking just at the directory layout of the [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/src/native_client/+/master/src/) that they are both part of the trusted service runtime code (they are in the `src/trusted/service_runtime` directory), and are therefore built with the system compiler and not subject to validation.
2. Yes, there is no limit on the number of instructions in a 32-byte bundle. The restriction is just that no instruction (or multi-instruction sandboxing sequence such as the one you mentioned for indirect jumps) may cross the bundle boundary. So in your example, both of those instructions would be required to be in the same bundle.
3. Again I'm a bit fuzzy on the details of how the trampolines work but when control transfers from the trampoline, it ends up in the service runtime, which is just ordinary machine code built according to the native ABIs for the OS. So the service runtime can use any system calls (at least any allowed by the outer sandbox) and can read or execute any part of the untrusted code.
4. The outer sandbox is, strictly speaking, a defense in depth (i.e. the inner sandbox is in theory sufficient to contain the untrusted code). It filters system calls in different ways on different OSes. In Chrome's embedding of NaCl, the outer sandbox is the same implementation as the Chrome sandbox used for the renderer and GPU processes.